# How can I make sibling elements respond together on hover?

Tags: html, css

**I am trying to make something that looks like a Neon sign that is supposed to "turn on" when you hover over it.**

Now I can make the individual h1 and p light up when I hover over them but not at the same time.

What I want is for when someone hovers over the h1 (or the paragraph) for them both to light up simultaneously.

**I thought something like #welcome_sign:hover would work but it doesn't.**

I'm unsure of where to go from here. Any suggestions?

```css
#welcome_sign h1:hover,
p:hover {
  color: #FFC2CE;
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 15px #FF0035;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-welcome">
  <div id="welcome_sign">
    <h1>Sammy Wagon </h1>
    <p>Try it. I dare you.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use the sibling selector `h1:hover, h1:hover + p { /* ... */}` or make use of the parent `#welcome_sign:hover>h1, #welcome_sign:hover>p { /* ... */}`

Comment: @GingerCampbell, please take the [tour] so you understand how this site works.